# mysql IN(), I want to retrieve data by receiving multiple type condition as parameter in product table

Tags: javascript, mysql

I want to retrieve data by receiving multiple type conditions as parameters in the products table. I tried using IN() as below. If I directly input IN(a,b) to query it, it works fine. But if you try it as a parameter, it won't work.

The query sent by Postman is as it follows:

```
?name=a&type=b,c&page=1
```

What am I doing wrong? Maybe the way I send the query is wrong? I need help.

```
const reviewSort = async (name, type, page) => {
  const sort = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT
      c.name AS category,
      t.name AS type,
      pr.name,
      pr.description,
      (SELECT COUNT(w.product_id)
        FROM products p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN product_wishlist w
        ON p.id = w.product_id
        WHERE p.id = pr.id) AS likeCount,
      COUNT(r.product_id) AS reviewCount,
      pr.price_origin
    FROM products pr
    JOIN category c ON c.id = pr.category_id
    JOIN product_types t ON t.id = pr.type_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN review r ON pr.id = r.product_id
    WHERE c.name = ? AND t.name IN (?)
    GROUP BY pr.id
    ORDER BY COUNT(r.product_id) DESC
    LIMIT ?, 9`,
    [name, type, (page - 1) * 9]
  );
  return sort;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should split the string into an array. Otherwise, it's trying to match the literal string `a,b`, not treat them as separate values in the `IN` list.

```
const reviewSort = async (name, type, page) => {
  const sort = await myDataSource.query(
    `SELECT
      c.name AS category,
      t.name AS type,
      pr.name,
      pr.description,
      (SELECT COUNT(w.product_id)
        FROM products p
        LEFT OUTER JOIN product_wishlist w
        ON p.id = w.product_id
        WHERE p.id = pr.id) AS likeCount,
      COUNT(r.product_id) AS reviewCount,
      pr.price_origin
    FROM products pr
    JOIN category c ON c.id = pr.category_id
    JOIN product_types t ON t.id = pr.type_id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN review r ON pr.id = r.product_id
    WHERE c.name = ? AND t.name IN (?)
    GROUP BY pr.id
    ORDER BY COUNT(r.product_id) DESC
    LIMIT ?, 9`,
    [name, type.split(','), (page - 1) * 9]
  );
  return sort;
};
```

Comment: The method you described gave me the results I wanted! thank you!